# How to use themes from Themeforest with JSF/Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, web, primefaces, themes

I wonder whether it is possible to use themes like these from Themeforest with my JSF/Primefaces. Could someone please explain me?

Comment: I doubt you can unless the have jquery ui compatible themes

Comment: What do you mean? Could you provide more details?

Comment: PrimeFaces uses jquery-ui compatible themesfor the components. So if you are looking for control themes they should be jquery-ui themes. If you are just looking for layout templates there is no relation with PrimeFaces or jsf in general

Comment: Thank you! I am disappointed.